# Определить куда отправляются введенные логин и пароль на сайте

Tags: html, веб-программирование

Решил вот написать Android-клиент на [эту](http://nebo.mobi) браузерную онлайн игру. Не в `WebView`, а нормальное приложение. Так вот, как такие делают, если игра не предоставляет API? Ясно дело, что на парсинге, но с ним дальше показа информации не зайдешь. Поизучав URL кнопок и других элементов я заметил, что игра полностью построена на ссылках типа `wicket-interface` и непонятных двоеточий. Так вот, опустив все случаи я беру во внимание саму логику входа. Как его реализовать программно, если неизвестно в какой php скрипт передаются данные игрока? Сниффера у меня нет, я его не знаю где найти.

Сама страница входа [вот](http://nebo.mobi/login). Код формы входа

```
<form action=";jsessionid=0CF652915C32981BD80F96D86167551D?wicket:interface=:0:loginForm:loginForm::IFormSubmitListener::" id="id1" method="post"><div style="width:0px;height:0px;position:absolute;left:-100px;top:-100px;overflow:hidden"><input type="hidden" name="id1_hf_0" id="id1_hf_0"></div>
<label>
Имя в игре<br>
<input maxlength="32" size="20" type="text" value="" name="login">
</label>
<br>
<label>
Пароль<br>
<input maxlength="32" size="20" type="password" value="" name="password">
</label>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Вход" class="submit" name=":submit" id="id2">
</form>
</div>
```

Еще интересно, как потом работать с игрой при последующих входах, сохранять надо что-то?

Comment: Нашел статью где пишут на php бота для этой игры, там ссылка в коде на вход есть, кому интересно вот > https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/108016/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для веб-страниц лучший сниффер - это браузер. В хроме консоль разработчика вызывается клавишей F12 (или Ctrl+Shift+I). Вкладка network предоставляет подробнейшую информацию о том какой информацией обмениваются страница и сервер, особенно при установленной галке "Preserve log". В других браузерах так же есть "Network" или "Сеть".

Comment: Спасибо, не знал

Comment: Крайне рекомендую воспользоваться плагином для хрома Postman Interceptor и приложением Postman. Interceptor перехватывает запросы к вебсерверу и сохраняет их в Postman, а Postman позволяет играться с любыми параметрами запросов. Неоценимая вещь, когда нужно проверить предположения о работе вебсервера и отладки API.